# Intent extras not changed

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an existing activity with a MediaPlayer that still running after onStop() was called.

I want to reload this activity but passing it different extra values.

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(WelcomeScreen.this, PlayMusic.class);
            intent.putExtra("plan", 0);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
            startActivity(intent);
```

But, that extra is "stuck" with the same values no matter what I put on the new intent.

Any ideas?

Comment: you question is not clear to me. "I have an existing activity with a MediaPlayer that still running after onStop() was called". do you not release media player in onStop?

Comment: no, I do not. My media keeps playing. That's why I use FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT. I don't want to recreate the activity, just change some of its properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you clearly state, you create a new Intent object. Whatever were the paramters associated with the old Intent, the one that was used to initially create the Activity, they were not affected.

However, you can access the new Intent by overriding Activity's [onNewIntent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29) method:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) 
{
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    if ( intent != null && intent.hasExtra("plan") )
    {
        // Yay! Do whatever... Live long... Prosper...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set new intent explicitly in `onNewIntent` callback

```
override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent)
    setIntent(intent)
}
```